# Underfull \hbox with \printindex and scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: koma-script, indexing, scrlayer-scrpage

While using `scrlayer-scrpage` in order to format my header for the KOMA-script class `scrartcl`, I am getting following warning in combination with `\printindex`:

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,parskip=half]{scrartcl}  % A4 paper and 12pt font size
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{makeidx}        % glossary
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex                  % make index

% Header
\clearpairofpagestyles      
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

Test\index{Test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Leaving `\printindex` out gets rid of the warning. How can I print my index page while using the above formating for header, without getting the warning?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in `scrlayer-scrpage`, because it appears also when the page style is not redefined and the package is loaded without any option.

Comment: Alright then, I switched to `scrpage2` package in order to format my headers. This way I got rid of the warning.

Comment: There was a small bug in `scrlayer` that is fixed in the [current version](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801) (not yet on CTAN).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was a bug that was fixed by the package author. Updating removes the issue.