# logo at the left & right at the header of a Book (two sided)

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to add logo in the header of a book. The logo should be either at the left or at the right corner w.r.t odd/even page. Please help me to correct my code:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4, % it's the default anyway
  fontsize=12pt,
  twoside
  ]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
    {%
 \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.eps}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.eps}}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-4\baselineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum 
\newpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered reading the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for starters? Your use of `\chead` with a nested `\fancyhead` is *wrong*.

Comment: Use `LO´ for left on odd page and ´RE´ for right on even pages, see the fancy hdr doc on page 6f.

Comment: @ Werner Yes, Its an error, I have modified it. Please help me next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `fancyhdr` uses some deprecated commands in its defaults. But that doesn't matter anymore, after using `\fancyhf` and clearing the defaults (thanks [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)).

I recommend using package `scrlayer-scrpage` from the KOMA-bundlea. The syntax is pretty similar. `\lehead` stands for the *left-even* head, `\rohead` for the *right-odd* head. The naming convention is similar for footers (`\lofoot`, `\cefoot` etc).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in,
paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\lehead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\rohead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Note: `book` sets the pagenumber in the outer head. Package `scrlayer-scrpage` will just overwrite that if requested by the user. Package `fancyhdr` just overwrites the settings of book without user interaction.

Comment: It's true that `fancyhdr` uses the deprecated `\rm` and `\sl` commands. However, when one does `\fancyhf{}`, that should *always* be done when using the package, those commands will have no effect. To the contrary, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219225/underfull-hbox-with-printindex-and-scrlayer-scrpage for an amusing bug of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Answer (score 4):

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) provides `O`dd and `E`ven-page placement as well as choosing between the `L`eft or `R`ight side of the page. So, for `L`eft-side on `O`dd pages, use `LO`, and `R`ight-side on `E`ven pages, use `RE`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Note that the `book` document class issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` on the first page of every `\chapter`. In those instances you'll lose your `fancy` page style, unless you re-issue `\pagestyle{fancy}` or redefined `plain`.